# Cannot get database data from Room Library

Tags: android, android-room

I am using `Room` for my android project. I was able to insert data successfully to the database but I cannot read that data from the database. I tried with lot of ways but no luck. No error also given. I use `LiveData`. I am not using `allowMainThreadQueries()`.

My Dao....

```
@Dao
public interface VehicleDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_login")
    LiveData<List<Vehicle>> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Vehicle... users);

}
```

My Database....

```
public abstract class DispatchDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static DispatchDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract VehicleDao vehicleDao();

    public static DispatchDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DispatchDatabase.class, "user-database").build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

MyViewModel....

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<Vehicle>> currentList;
    private DispatchDatabase appDataBase;

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        appDataBase = DispatchDatabase.getAppDatabase(application.getApplicationContext());
        currentList = appDataBase.vehicleDao().getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Vehicle>> getCurrentData() {
        return currentList;
    }
}
```

My activity....

```
 MyViewModel mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
mViewModel.getCurrentData().observe(LoginActivity.this, new Observer<List<Vehicle>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        Log.d("vehicleNumber : ", String.valueOf(vehicles.size()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you mentioned the tables in database class?

Comment: @Jaymin. yes like this - **@Database(entities = {Vehicle.class}, version = 1)**

Comment: Try with same observer pattern for `appDataBase.vehicleDao().getAll();`

Comment: I have already tried for that ||| look at MyViewModel class **currentList = appDataBase.vehicleDao().getAll();**